# html2canvas offscreen

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

In using html2canvas, I have a `stack` of DOM objects (relative positioned div's that contain various things), that I wish to create individual thumbnails for. So if there are ten divs, I will create ten thumbnails.

Some of these objects will be offscreen --each of these divs are in a single, encompassing div called "mainDiv". I iterate through the divs within mainDiv and execute the html2canvas on each of them individually.

For those that are onscreen, this works fine. Those that are offscreen do not -- they come back blank. I created a workaround that scrolls the objects to the top of the `mainDiv`, however this is a kludge and visually unappealing.

Is it possible to specify a DOM object that is not visible? Ideally, I'd like to be able to specify a containing div and have `html2canvas` ignore the parent visibility, so I can screen capture hidden objects, but barring that, I'd like to be able to screen capture objects that are simply scrolled off screen.

Any thoughts, ideas? Thanks!

---- Here is some example code. Basically, if you had a bunch of divs within a div, iterate through them. I actually do this `recursively` so that only one gets processed at a time, with the callback calling the recursive function, so it looks something like this:

```
  function recurser(anIndex, callback) {
    if (anIndex == -1) {
        callback();
        return;
    }
    $(myDivs[anIndex]).html2canvas({
        onrendered : function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL();
            // store the image in an array, do stuff with it, etc.
            recurser(--anIndex, callback);

        }
    })

}
```

Once the recursive calls are complete, it executes the callback function, which is a function that will do stuff with the images.

Again, all this works fine as long as the objects are visible within the scrolling div that contains all of the divs in #mainDiv. Once any part of the divs are scrolled off, however, they render black. In fact, if half of two divs are scrolled off (the top half of one, the bottom half of the next), they both render completely black.

Comment: Please attach some code examples.

Comment: @sneuf Is this for any specific browser or do you see this behavior across browsers?

Answer (score 29):

I know this is an old question but it seemed kind of interesting. Based on my testing it seemed like only `position: absolute` and `position:fixed` elements that were outside of the viewport caused this issue. I figured out a solution to the problem.

What I'm doing is making a clone of the element. Setting the styling of the clone to `left = 0`, `top = window.innerHeight` (so that it won't be inside the window) and `position = 'relative'`. Then I append the clone to the body, use `html2canvas` on the clone, and then remove the clone from the body. This solution works for me in IE, Firefox, and Chrome.

I have created a [JSBin example here](http://jsbin.com/kocigo/2/edit?css,js,output). Here is the key javascript code:

```
function hiddenClone(element){
  // Create clone of element
  var clone = element.cloneNode(true);

  // Position element relatively within the 
  // body but still out of the viewport
  var style = clone.style;
  style.position = 'relative';
  style.top = window.innerHeight + 'px';
  style.left = 0;

  // Append clone to body and return the clone
  document.body.appendChild(clone);
  return clone;
}

var offScreen = document.querySelector('.off-screen');

// Clone off-screen element
var clone = hiddenClone(offScreen);

// Use clone with htm2canvas and delete clone
html2canvas(clone, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      document.body.removeChild(clone);
    }
});
```

Comment: good pickup on this.  IMO this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks pseudosavant !!

Comment: not working here: for some reason not everything in the div is cloned correctly.

Comment: @cmbarbu Can you provide more details? What browser are you using? Can you setup a jsbin that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @pseudosavant I'm not much motivated right now to set up a jsbin as I found a better solution: it was a plot in Flot, it's easier and it looks better to replot it completely as a miniature. I'll ask an other question if I come back to that solution, Thanks anyway

Comment: i get screenshot of the div without css why?

Comment: The 'hidden' clone is being attached to `<body>`. That could be making the element not match some of the selectors in your CSS. Try changing the code so that the `clone` element is appended/removed from `clone.parentNode`.

Comment: Although that will probably make the cloned element off screen. You might just have to tweak your CSS selectors so that the element still matches.

Answer (score 4):

set 'overflow' as visible for all of its parent elements. After rendered remove it

CSS

```
.overflowVisible{
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```

JS

```
$("#container").parents().each(function(ind,elem){
    $(elem).addClass("overflowVisible");
});

html2canvas($("#container"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var img =canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        $('body').append(img);
        $("#container").parents().each(function(ind,elem){
            $(elem).removeClass("overflowVisible");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the latest version of html2canvas. This resolves all images pix-elation issues and rendering object issue. I used the version 0.5.0-beta4 by Erik koopmans [refer this](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/622) and called the html2canvas as below:

```
$('html,body').scrollTop(0); // Take your <div> / html at top position before calling html2canvas

     html2canvas( $("#my_div"), {
         useCORS: true,
         dpi: 200,

          onrendered:function(canvas) {

              var str = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
              var contentType = 'image/png';
              console.log(str);
              b64Data =str;
              $('#uploadedImage').val(b64Data); // set image captured by html2canvas
              imgFrameSave(); // Call a function to save your image at server side.
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah now have you tried Div display: none; and Div display: absolute; (or how you'd like your div to appear - maybe z-index)

```
    arrow1.onclick = (event){
arrow1.style.display = none;
arrow2.style.display = absolute;
}

    arrow2.onclick = (event){
arrow2.style.display = none;
arrow1.style.display = absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
{
    scrollX: -window.scrollX,
    scrollY: -window.scrollY
}
```

Based on: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1878#issuecomment-511678281