# Captured HTML div with html2canvas is not full

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I'm working on a meme editor website using the html2canvas library from https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

here is my html code for the `div` that I need to capture:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="theUserMeme">

        <div class="row">

            <p id="memeWords">
                When I see something lol 

            </p>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <img id = "memeImage" src="images/init meme.jpg">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Also, this my JavaScript code that I run to capture the `div`:

```
function generateMeme(){

    window.scrollTo(0,0);

    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#theUserMeme")).then(canvas => {
        
        var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1);
        console.log(image);
        
        alert(image);

        document.getElementById("finalImageCopy").src = image;
    });


}
```

After hosting the code on Github, I tried the page on my iPhone and my laptop. It was working well on both devices, but after that it is working on the phone only. When I use it on the desktop, the captured image isn't full and sometimes it is only white image.

What is the problem could be?

Comment: Perhaps something in your CSS that interfere.

Comment: are you running from localhost by chance? did you check javascript console for errors?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I'm running from GitHub hosting. It can be found under shaath404.github.io

Comment: @vanowm Well, I'm using bootstrap. Is it this problem

Comment: see these possibilities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591339/html2canvas-offscreen

Answer (score 0):

It seems by default width of a `<div>` is equal to width of the visible area (please correctly if I'm wrong) and if an image is larger it doesn't "stretch" the div, it simply overflows out of it

So one way to fix this is to add `width: fit-content;` to your element:
https://jsfiddle.net/vanowm/h5yroe2q/

```js
function generateMeme(id, options){

    window.scrollTo(0,0);
        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#theUserMeme"), options).then(canvas => {
        console.log(canvas);
        var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1);
        console.log(image);
        

        document.getElementById(id || "finalImageCopy").src = image;
    });


}
//generate first image
generateMeme();

//generate second image with adding options to html2canvas
generateMeme("finalImageCopy2", {
   width: document.querySelector("#theUserMeme").scrollWidth
});

//set width
document.querySelector("#theUserMeme").style.width = "fit-content";

//generate third image
generateMeme("finalImageCopy3");
```

```css
body
{
  width: 50px;
}

pre
{
  width: fit-content;
}

pre > img
{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div id="theUserMeme">

        <div class="row">

            <p id="memeWords">
                When I see something lol 

            </p>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <img id = "memeImage" src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEABALDBoYFhoaGRodHRofIh8iIB0iHSUfJR8dLigyMC0nLS00PVBCNDhLOSstRWFFS1NWW1xbMkFlbWRYbFBZW1cBERISGBYZLRcaLVc2NTZXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV//AABEIAMgBLAMBEQACEQEDEQH/xAAaAAEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIEAwUG/8QAOxAAAgIAAwQFCQYHAQEAAAAAAAECEQMhMQQSQVEFImFxkRMUFTJTgZKh0UJyscHh8AYjM0NSYsKCsv/EABkBAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBf/EACQRAQEBAAIBBQADAQEBAAAAAAARAQISEwMhMVFhFCJBQjIj/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDJ9Z8ZAAFAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKQAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKRQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABqeG0k3o1aZM5Zq7x3GSoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFIoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA6tmXlISwvtetDv4r3nLlvXl2duGd+PT6+HLR1riAAFAAAAAAAAKAUAoBQCgFAKAAKAUAoBQFoilAKAUAoBQCgFAKAUAoBQCgFAKA1CTjJSWqdozyzNyNcd3jtx17fhJ7uLH1Z69kjn6XL/nfnHX1uOf+8+NcVHZwKAUAoBQCgFAKAUAoBQCgFChQCgFAKAUAoBQoUBqjLRQCgFAKAUAoBQCgFAKAUAoBQCgFAd/R0lJSwZaSzXYzh6t47nPHp9Gcs309ceLhOEnF6o7ZyuV5+XHeOzWKKyUAoBQCgFAKAUAClAKAAAAAIUAABSgFAjRlQAA3RSNwwpPSLrnRN5ZjWcd12ro9Nauzn5NdvDjhxMNxk0+B0za4bk2MlQAAAAAAAAAWEnFprVZom5cjXHeu3H0dvw1iYccaPLPu/Q4ely67016fW49sznj5tHpeQoBQCgFECgFAKAUAoBQCgN4cOZN1rMer2a/VM9410vw8/INSppmu2M9Nr1extq459hnyY34t/wAYwsF3nF9xd5YznHXTg7BvW5KuRz31Z8OvH0b8vDadilh56x5/U3x9TOTnz9PeLn3WbrEaoix6Rw4uszNazMdENlizG89x0z0811YWAlkc95brrx45ns6YJJUsjDp7ZjMXRUfM2yE3K5ZJ6Lkjvw3J7PNzzb7rh9HuWdpLuG+pDPS3WcTo/EWdKS7GM9TNTfS5Y83ss1rFmu+M9NeTjRqpCgkKBCgQoEKFIUCPodF4yzw5aPTv4o8/q5/1j0+hy/41y7Xs/k5tcNV3HXhz7ZXHnw67HhRtiLQpChSFCkKFIUKQoEKBCgQoEKBGosi46cKaMbjrx11QZz10x0wkjDoboI1HIi41vLRoi+y+TjyRLpMfn3HsPXXiirDd1WYuHXXbs2yS4ya7Dly5u3H09dOJgtLqyz5Mzm5vy6bx3Ph4rGaynk/xLM/xntv+vSDzJq49pQUtUmZsa3M16YeWVUkTWsJxvQYbjzmm0axnXDtOEmnz5nXjrjz444aOjiUAoUKAUAoCq07WqJvuue3u78SSx8LT+ZDOuaOOf038ejf/AKcb/uPn0d68yqLeiJVmr5N8n4C4ddTdfIXCalFqQAAKAUAoBQCgKgr0hitaMzuNZuvfCx3xMbjfHlrpjtBnq32a84ROrXZXioQ7NLGJFqrBRKdWnhXWSy0FXqssiK8ZZ8TWM65sfC3pJm82Oe8br3hGtTOt49d9IzGqw8YsStLaMidTsKdg+XntWzprWma48mefF8xx7DrXCJRSFBCgpQCgFAjp2S4701rW7Ff5TeSRy9Tf8dvR4+9c2x4uNhpxxfJympSt7t8edkzjc+V5c5sjsXSWIuEPBr8x4/083416TxOUfmPHh5t+k9JT5R+ZfHiebfpH0hL/ABh4Dx4eXfpl7a39iHwl6fqeT8Ye03/bh8Jev6z3/HnOV/ZS7kaz2Z33YoqFAhQCgFAgBpSZBd5hUCLvMD0WM+ZI1X0I4pxj0Vt4oi15zxLDO6kGUxcSDUk7VA3GJSsIyUebKy1EivaE6I1mrKa4sQ3XHtM06o3jly93PRpmLQIUCFAhQIuHhuTSWrJuxc43Y9o9baMJL+nht1/tOs5HH5uvR8bnHHjiL+ZiffkdOHw4+pn9ko3WIUKQoEKFIUKQoUhQpChSFAhQpEoUhQpFoUhQpChSFCkUlChSPeEm3kYdW2pEVZJ5AWMqA9FibwX5ec41mEjzcyozvlQWIBXjEWsTxGys686KhQFoBQIUCFAjpwobsHLjL5ROfLbsduOdcus7Jnix5cF7i77Yzx9+VeOL/Vxfvv8ABF4fCc/lKNMJQIAgABAEAAAEAAIAhQFoBQCgFAKA6XOK0MOq4WI3JL90TTHniYrbZU1lN8wLvUBHJgZKhQIUAoIUKQoEKFIUCFCkKFI9MDC3pdizfcTda48a1tGJvOloiZi8tq7Ev5sff+A5fBwz3eE/6uL9/wDJDj8HPPco0zCgQoUhQIUKQoUhQIUCFCkKFIUKQoUhQIUKQoUhQpChSFAjai3pmZajcU4XaabVLLxIuY86KkKAUCFAhQIUCFAhQIUKQoUhQpChSFCkKFI6J9SG6vWepPlr4yOcrMe+xL+ZH3/gTWuPy5pf1cb7y/8AlDPg5fLVFZKFICgKQFIUKQFICkBSApAUgKQFI0l1X3oUjNAhQAEAR7PHn/k13ZGW0Umkn/t45PUgYkF60dOXJ8i0jAqFCkKFIUKQoUiUKQoUhQpFoUiUKQoUi0KR6YMa6z0WnawuMSbbtgZoVHRsS/mLuf4E3Wsc0v62N95fgXE1qhUhQpChSFCkKFIUKQoUhQpChSFCkKFIUKQoUa+zXG791BWaFQoUiUKQoUjdEaiyXVX3/wDlhSEq7uK5oBKPLQIlEIUCFAhQIUUKIQoEKBCgQoEKKRqbulwQGaAUB7bH667mRXL/AHsbvj+BRughQIUBaBEoEKBFoESgRaBCgQoEEgRtSS0Vvm/oCEpvJ3n1vDIKjinpk+X0CRmgQoEKBFoy1Fn6sfv/APLKJQCiBRSFAhRAopCgQoEKBCgQoEKBCgQoEKBCgR77J667mByf38bvj+AHpRCFFIUSkKKQoEKIQopCgQoEKBCgQoEKBFekf/X5ASgACgFAjRlon6sfv/8ALKhRFKAAAgFKAlAUBQCgM7y5rxCObG6RwYb14kbjrFO33UampXP6dwP9/gZemnbD07s/OfwMdNO2Hp7Z+c/gY6aXD09s/OXwMdNO2OvorpXBxsZQg5b1N5xayJ13CufaukMPA2jFWI3nu1UW+Beu6Vj09s/OXwMdNO2Hp7Z+c/gY6adsPTuz85/Ax007YencD/f4GOmnbHtg9K4E0n5RK+Euq/AnXS4695c14kaUgtAKAUAoBQABL7P/AK/5KhRFKAAAPza23F9pLxOF1w7ar23FqvKSq74ajtp2089xfaS8R207avnmL7SXiTtp2088xfaSHbTtqee4vtJeJc3lvwXR7Zi+0l4ov91usYnSWJF05z92Zvjw5770us+lZ59fEy7DXi5/Z7sy6WxuEpV2p2bz0vb31fdPSuPzl8y+PPsuvF7dj1ni4lfkbmF1yeTSrJ/CaCux5a5foBK79f8AH9AG7mln4foBEstH25foA3e/w1+QH2v4VjW2R19WfDsM8lxn+JY3tUu5cLHE18dx7/D9DTJXf2ZfoBVHNLPTl+gBLXXh9n9ALXY/h/QKvk1yfwgdGHteLGKjHExElkktEiTCuhdKY+m9LvzOfi/Si6WxuMpVx1Jvpe3tpdb9LT/zxPAx4uf2XWodJYjdb80+3Izvp88y1Lr088xfaPxRj+5dPPMX2kvEm7yz5Lqee4vtJeJO2pdPPMX2kvEdtLp55i+0l4jtpdPPMX2kvEdtLp55i+0kO2l1xOSy61fmWI0u8gqYF3srAjfaxBybe06jvLm7v3cD0+hntVxyPCWS3ofPV+7uO6nkk5etCl36L3BSMNXvQ8Xq/cA8nl60PF/QBLDyXWhxer+gRZYeaW9HRLV6+AFUE5XvR15vh7gMxw8n1o6c39AL5PqvrR1XFgHh5LrR1fF9gCWHp1o6cwNLC63rR1XED7P8JQrbU96L6uJo+wzy+GsZ/iuN7S80slq6HFNfInh9ddaOq4mkZjh5+tHR8ewBGGvWjpz7QCh1fWjrzYElhZLrR48Xz7gLKGae9Hg9X9AL5NKVb0eK1fH3AZhha9aGnbw9wDyar1oZPm/oAeHkuvDlq/oRSUFvXvQ56v38O8oLBVtb0Pn7uAR1dHyUZOO9F72dK9fA4evlyo75RPKiXXFgG+0C33APegJl9SjOV/vxAq7n4AL7OYDuA58TYlOTk2+6uB34+t1yRaz6Ozvf58C+f8KyujaXr/IefPoq+jcq3s+4efPoqejtOvz4Dz59FJdHcd7lwL58+itLo3rXv8b0H8jPorK6Ma+3qnw/UfyM+ino10+svAfyM+ino51W8ueg8+fRSXRry6y48B/Iz6Lg+jW/tLRLQefC4r2BqV7y1Tqh58+ivo9AQjs+0rEnLq7slkuLG+tx32XNms9ORW0YznB9WlqhnrccN1wT6Pd3vLVPRl8+fRU9HO73lx4E/kYUj0a19pZqtB/Iz6Si6OdNb6zrhyHnxano7Kt9c9B58+ko+jckt75Dz59FWXR9v1+XAefPoqro/O973UPPn0VF0fr1+HIef8KR6Oy9f5E8+fRR9G5Lr/Ief8KPo5Zdd6ch5/wr0hsKUlJS43oZ5etckHWmjgGXgQSkVEpcgL7gCAjlXzAXy8Cgr4agbz40QRt2Afa9QJvfvQBdr9QIrYFsDSfz0yAm88skwKtSBfYAUuzjzAAE70KDtfvQCZ8suQEt60Abb4AbUXXayCacAIu4oZ8OIBNMBxqsgJbvSgKlnoBFl2/UDSXNfMgjb5UUZefDICrwAmi0AqAgBx42yi5eICKXDvse4u7V/MCPh4kF8Hp3gGuYC0l+8gMqSRYLGfZx4Eg0pdogb2eYB9nKwG9l+YGZSqtedjMGfOF77a9xeoqxdbV93IdRpSyuiQai7+fEgKarIQSUkv3xKI5JagVOq49gGd7P5iCqaf748hAlPXL6CAn2aAZU89M/xLAjip6cf39BBVPOtSQPKIQN/LXmBV+7Ayn29nvEFbQByV0nnyAliCNp8Sj/2Q==">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<pre>

Captured image:
<img id="finalImageCopy">


Captured image manually set canvas width:
<img id="finalImageCopy2">


Captured image with <b>width: fit-content</b>:
<img id="finalImageCopy3">
</pre>
```

Comment: How to do this with bootstrap?

Comment: The same way you used it before...not sure what's your question is about...

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution didn’t work in bootstrap.

Comment: since "didn't work" really tells nothing, my only guess is there is something else interfering.